how to center in contraint layout

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".lobby">


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sr"
        android:textSize="30sp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="leaderboard"
        android:textSize="30sp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="score"
        android:textSize="30sp">

    </TextView>
</GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
